# GAE Standard: In what cases would I actually require a single instance to run permanently vs. spinning up only when there's user activity?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-standard, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to create a website on GAE utilizing the Node.js Standard environment. The website will be a two-sided marketplace (similar to Fiverr, Uber, Airbnb, etc.) where I'd be performing back-end logic and CRUD updates with the Cloud Firestore database. I'm also looking to leverage Firebase Authentication, Cloud Storage, Cloud Functions, and Cloud Messaging.

Given my use case above, am I okay with just using the F1 instance class with the auto_scaling option that only creates an instance with actual user activity on my website (assuming low user activity)? If not, why?

What limitations should I keep in mind that may cause me problems right off the bat or in the near future? Roughly how much user activity would make this impractical? Why?

Answer (score 0):

As with any website, do load tests for expected amount of traffic and monitor your application and logs to review any issues.  Even if low traffic - test that.  Check for cold start times.  If the app takes too long to start cold with low traffic - then look at options.  That may include optimizing the app to startup faster, keep one instance always on, or keep an instance warm by setting up a cron to hit a warmup url.

Answer (score 0):

Using a F1 instance for that use case is perfectly fine.

About the limitations, for your use case the setting you described is alright; limitations might appear if you add logic to the app, like different business logic which would require more powerful machines.

About how much user activity: This is a bit subjective, as it depends on the application's code; but also, if you have auto_scaling enabled, it would take care of the situation and horizontally scale your app.